# Multiple Knapsack Algo Implementation

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I need to apply multiple knapsack in C# with multiple knapsacks and items having same weight.

Is there any simple implementation in C# or infact any other language for which I can refer.

Currently I have written code to create the knapsacks and subset of items though I am struggling to implement algo.

Any Suggestion or code snippet would be helpful.

```
I am looking to fill multiple knapsacks in c# with equal weight and unequal sizes.
```

Comment: What kind of algorithm are you looking for? An exact algorithm, a heuristic or an approximation algorithm?

Comment: Exact would be great but anything will help

Comment: You could try [this reference](http://www.diku.dk/~pisinger/codes.html) which provides an implementation in `C`. You could try to port it to C#. Furthermore, the question can be seen as asking for a generalization of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786941/optimal-way-of-filling-2-knapsacks).